# Object movement issues in python

Tags: python

If youre reading this I appreciate your time and would like to thank you in advance.

So the current goal of mine is to have neutrons shooting in random directions with random speeds at a source (x,y).

Ive ran into a bunch of related problems that I cant fix with my knowledge in the moment (im quite inexperienced in programming)

The Problems are the following:

1.
The "move" method in the Program is not working as intended = With every generation of a new object (Neutron class) the objects get faster.

2.

I cant assign the move methon to the objects in the "neutrons" list individually. Its either that all objects move in the same direction

with the same speed or only the last element of the "neutrons" list moves and the rest stay still.

The example in the program:

```
for n in neutrons:
    n.draw(screen)
    neutrons[-1].move(angle_list, neutr_v_list)  #newest neutron moves, the rest stays still

    n.move(angle_list, neutr_v_list)    #Every Neutron moves the same
```

3. 

If I define the "move" method as the following:

```
self.x += math.cos(random.randint(0,360)) \* 2
self.y += math.sin(random.randint(0,360)) * 2
```

What happens is that in this loop:

```
for n in neutrons:
    n.move()
```

the random values get generated over and over again which causes the individual objects not move in a straight line. They move like a bee thats been fed some caffeine.

The ultimate goal at the moment is when an object (neutron in this scenario) hits another object (a uranium atom) it should generate 3 new neutrons in the x,y of the collision and the neutrons should fly off in random directions and potentially hit another Uranium atom.

Github link to the program: https://github.com/Magicalsauce69/Nuclear-simulation-in-python.git

Full code:

```
#imports

from typing_extensions import Self
import pygame

#Imports

import pygame as py
import os
import random 
import math
import time
from random import *
import random

#Framerate

FPS = 60

#Creating the lists

angle_list = []
neutrons = []    
neutr_v_list = []


#Colors 

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (51, 51, 255)
LIGHT_BLUE = (173,216,230)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
PURPLE = (204, 0, 204)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)


#Creating a window

py.init

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 700  #aspect ratio is  ...
screen = py.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
py.display.set_caption("Starting to loose it")


#function that gets called in the mainloop that draws stuff on the screen

def draw_screen():
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    py.display.update()


#The Neutron class

class c_Neutron():
    def __init__(self, x, y, r, v, name,):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y 
            self.r = r
            self.v = v
            self.name = name
            self.color = LIGHT_BLUE
    
    def draw(self, screen):
        py.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x - self.r, self.y - self.r), self.r, 10)
        


    def move(self, angle_list, neutr_v_list):
            self.x += math.cos(angle_list[-1]) * neutr_v_list[-1]    #Im trying to generate random directions and speeds for every neutron specifically
            self.y += math.sin(angle_list[-1]) * neutr_v_list[-1]     #Another issue is that they get faster with every neutron generated



        

#The Uran class
        
class n_Uran():

    def __init__(self, x, y, r,):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
    
        self.color = [RED]

    def draw(self, screen):
        py.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x - self.r, self.y - self.r), self.r, 10)




#Amount of Neutrons
Anz_neutronen = len(neutrons)   #Should return how many elements are in the list
print(Anz_neutronen)





#Mainloop

def main():
    
    
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keydown_list = []
    
        

    while True:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    keydown_list.append(1)
                    print(len(keydown_list))   
                    neutrons.append(c_Neutron(200,200,5,random.randint(1,3),"")  )
                    angle_list.append(random.randint(0, 360))
                    neutr_v_list.append(random.randint(1, 3))

                    print(neutrons)


        screen.fill(WHITE)
                             
        for n in neutrons:                    
            n.draw(screen)
            neutrons[-1].move(angle_list, neutr_v_list)           #Only the newest neutron moves and the rest stays still
            n.move(angle_list, neutr_v_list)                       #Every Neutron moves the same


        
        py.display.update()                           
        clock.tick(FPS)

#Run the main game loop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: When calling `n.move(angle_list, neutr_v_list)` you're telling each neutron to move but you're passing the exact same parameters (angle_list, neutr_v_list) to each neutron. Perhaps you need to maintain these things per-neutron as instance variables or you calculate them anew for each neutron, instead of once and then applying the same values to every neutron.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**
I didn't encounter this problem; it may have just happened by chance in your test. Either way, it doesn't happen with the code I have created.

**Problem 2**
You have tried two ways of doing this, but neither of them work, for the following reasons:

- When you use `n.move(angle_list, neutr_v_list)`, you are passing the same parameters to each neutron, so of course they all move in the same way.
- When you use `neutrons[-1].move(angle_list, neutr_v_list)`, `neutrons[-1]` refers to the last object in the list `neutrons`, so only the last neutron ever gets moved.

The correct way to get this to work would be to store the angle and velocity of each neutron as an attribute of that neuron, and not make the `move` method take any attributes.

**Problem 3**
Here you tried a different way of solving problem 2, which also didn't work, for the reason you stated in your question.

The right way of doing this is to just generate a random value once when each neutron is created, and store it as an attribute of that neutron, as I said above.

**The working code**
Here is my working version of your code. I also changed a few other things about it:

- The formatting and variable names, to fit PEP8
- I added a base `Particle` class for both `Neutron` and `Uranium` to inherit from, to avoid code duplication
- `pygame.init` -> `pygame.init()` and is now inside `main()`
- Moved some other code to be inside `main()`
- Removed duplicate imports and made all uses of PyGame be `pygame` not `py`
- Instead of calculating how much the X and Y of each neutron should change every time, used a `cached_property` for each one to only calculate them once
- Some other minor things that have little effect

```py
import os
import random
import math
import time
import sys

import pygame

try:
    # Python 3.8+ only
    from functools import cached_property
except ImportError:
    # Does the same exact thing, but works on all python versions
    # Remove this if guaranteed to be using Python 3.8+
    from functools import lru_cache
    cached_property = lambda method: property(
        lru_cache(maxsize=None)(method)
    )

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (51, 51, 255)
LIGHT_BLUE = (173, 216, 230)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
PURPLE = (204, 0, 204)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)

FPS = 60
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 600


class Particle:

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(
            screen,
            self.color,
            (int(self.x - self.radius // 2), int(self.y - self.radius // 2)),
            self.radius,
        )


class Neutron(Particle):

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, velocity, angle):
        super().__init__(x, y, radius, color=LIGHT_BLUE)
        
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.angle = angle

    @cached_property
    def dx(self):
        return math.cos(self.angle) * self.velocity

    @cached_property
    def dy(self):
        return math.sin(self.angle) * self.velocity

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy

        
class Uranium(Particle):

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        super().__init__(x, y, radius, color=RED)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Starting to lose it")
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    neutrons = []

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    neutrons.append(Neutron(
                        x=int(WIDTH // 2),
                        y=int(HEIGHT // 2),
                        radius=5,
                        velocity=random.randint(1, 3),
                        angle=random.randint(1, 360)
                    ))

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        for n in neutrons:
            n.draw(screen)
            n.move()

        pygame.display.update()                           
        clock.tick(FPS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Managed to solve it in the meantime aswell and I honestly should have seen the issue earlier. Regardless thanks a lot because the fix and the explanaiton are both really good. I appreciate your time and effort. Thank you :)